# Java Application on Virtual Machine Performance

Tags: java, performance, virtual-machine

I implemented a Java Application over my personal machine. The application execution time takes about 20 seconds on my machine. I migrated to a server machine that is 10x as powerful as my personal machine. Unfortunately, the application takes on this server machine twice the execution time. I am pretty sure JVM version and settings are same on both machine, both works as server not client and both run Windows 7

The only thing I suspect that the OS on my machine is native while the OS of the server is run on a virtual machine with dedicated huge memory and 2 physical processors. Am I right? Does running Java Application in a Windows virtual machine impacts the performance despite having 10x more powerful hardware?

Comment: You need to be far more specific. What is 10x more powerful, what makes it more powerful, have you run benchmarks to confirm?

Comment: There are too many factors here to give a specific answer. In general, all other things being equal, software will *always* run slower in a virtualized environment due to the overhead imposed by the VM manager (you don't specify which one you are using). Further, there could be all kind of constraints in the configuration of your specific VM manager, hardware virtualization settings, etc. You need to give more detail.

Comment: For single-threaded CPU-limited tasks, *nothing in existence* is 10x more powerful than your personal machine.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - you clearly have not seen my homemade quantum machine that I keep in the freezer...

Comment: @chrsva Share your invention with the world!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - sadly, the time is not yet ripe. But it will come, it will come...

Answer (score 0):

I have had first-hand experience with massive server systems (from Sun) which had enormous concurrent I/O throughput, but each specific CPU core was *less powerful* than a high-end desktop machine. It is quite possible that the task you are running is loading that system in a way which it has not been optimized for.

On the other hand, there are many other factors to consider, such as what the rest of that system was doing while you were making your measurements, what exactly you were doing, was the JIT compiler involved properly, etc.